# Need help in post build event. Xcopy from debug to C:\testing

Tags: c#, xcopy

I read the question with XCOPY but my one is a bit unique

I am trying to copy from the Debug directory to c:\testing

```
xcopy $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)\ c:\testing
```

It keep telling me it exit with code 4. I tried a lot of variations but still cannot get this simple code to work. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Just for knowledge building, I found the answer

start xcopy "$(TargetDir)*.*" c:\testing